# Double condition in array with JQ

Tags: jq

My JSON is an array of one object like this:

```json
[{
  "id": 125650,
  "status": "success",
  "name": "build_job",
  "artifacts": [
    {
      "file_type": "archive",
      "size": 72720116,
      "filename": "artifacts.zip",
      "file_format": "zip"
    },
    {
      "file_type": "metadata",
      "size": 1406,
      "filename": "metadata.gz",
      "file_format": "gzip"
    }
  ]
}]
```

I want to select only the object ID if the following conditions matches:

- status == success
- name == build_job
- artifacts.size > 0 where file_type == archive

I'm stuck on the last condition, I can select artifacts with size > 0, OR artifacts where file_type = archive, but not both at the same time.

Here's my current query :

```sh
| jq '.[0] | select(.name == "build_job" and .status == "success" and .artifacts[].file_type == "archive") | .id'
```

Can you help me with that ?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try this:

```
.[0] | select(
  .name == "build_job" and .status == "success" and (
      .artifacts[] | select(.file_type == "archive") | length > 0
   )
) | .id
```

This selects successful `build_job`s containing one or more `archive` artifacts. Unfortunately, multiple ids are returned if there's more than one such artifacts. Here's how to wrap the expression to fix that:

```
[ 
  .[] | select(
    .name == "build_job" and .status == "success" and (
      .artifacts[] | select(.file_type == "archive") | length > 0
    )
  )
] | unique | .[].id
```

Comment: You inspired me, thanks! I achieved what I needed with the following query: `jq '.[0] | select(.name == "build_job" and .status == "success" and ( .artifacts[] | select(.file_type == "archive" and .size > 0))) | .id'`

Comment: Ah, yes, I'm sorry, I failed to understand the `.size` part of the query. :-)

Answer (score 1):

For the last condition, you presumably mean something like:

```
all(.artifacts[];
    if .file_type == "archive" then .size > 0 else true end)
```

which can also be written as:

```
all(.artifacts[] | select(.file_type == "archive");
    .size > 0)
```

I’d recommend using either `all` or `any`, depending on your requirements.

Answer (score -1):

For the last condition, take the array `.artifacts`, reduce it to those elements matching your criteria `map(select(.file_type == "archive"))` and test the resulting array's length `length > 0`.

All together:

```
.[0] | select(
  .name == "build_job" and
  .status == "success" and (
    (.artifacts | map(select(.file_type == "archive"))) | length > 0
  )
)
| .id
```

Comment: The Q refers to .size ....